# How to create sheet in excel listing data from other sheets

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with multiple sheets. Each sheet contains the columns "name", "age", "class". Here is what I'm trying to do. When a name, age, and class from a sheet matches a name, age, and class from any other sheet, I want to create a new sheet that list those names, age and class. My goal is to have separate sheets that include all of the people who are the same age and in the same class.

It would also be great if there is a way to dynamically name the sheet when it is created using "age / class".

Is this a difficult task? I've made some attempt and have googled without success.

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: I think this will do exactly what I need, but I can't seem to get the sample sheet to work to make sure. I downloaded the file, pressed Alt-F8 and ran the ConsolidateSheets macro, but I get a "Compile error: Named argument not found" message.

Comment: Since I was using the file provided, I didn't think I needed to. I believe I found a work around for now by using the built in "consolidate" tool in Excel. Doesn't do exactly what i want, but it will do for now. Thanks for your help.